# Angular 2. How to get queryParams in component?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have task - to transmit some params in App component of Angular 2 application through URL.

The best way i found to do it - using `queryParams`. But i not found best way to parse these params.

I'm sure that using `ActivatedRoute` will solve my task (and i know how to import it and how to use in constructor) but i'm not sure how to extract `queryParams` using it.

Can you help me in it?

Unfortunately i couldn't run my code in plunker(couldn't find properly example on Angular 2), attaching it as is.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [],
  template: 
  `
  <button (click)="testLink()">Make link</button>
  <button (click)="checkEntity()">Check Params</button>
  `
})
export class App {
  entity: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  checkEntity(){
    this.entity = this.route
      .queryParams
      .map(params => params['entity'] || 'None');

    if(this.entity) alert('It works!');
  }

  testLink(){
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { 'entity': 'user' }
    };

    this.router.navigate(['/'], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

Last step - to get queryParams in `entity`.
This code using `Observable` but for me will be enough single check.

Comment: Did you try a search here on SO? Did you check the docs at http://angular.io?

Comment: Yes, red docs on angular.io, i found close to complete solution but i can't realize the last step. I making plunker solution now to make my question more representative.

Comment: Then please post the code that demonstrates what you tried and where you're stuck and error messages if you get some. We can't know what "the last step" was for you.

Comment: Sure. I understood that i was must to attach the code with question creation.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i added my code. So, you can see that "last step".

Comment: I'm having the same problems.  I can't believe how much complexity RC6 has for pulling a static value out of the URL.  I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Did you try and add `....map(...).subscribe((entity: any) => this.entity = entity);` to retrieve the value from the Observable

Answer (score 2):

I am passing parameters in my ionic 4 app like this. All that is missing in the code is to:

1. subscribe to the observable when retrieving
2. stringify the query parameters when passing

```
    export class App {
      entity: any;
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

      checkEntity() {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { 
          if (params) {
            if (params.entity) {
              alert('It works!'); 
            } 
          } 
        })
      }

      testLink() {
        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { 
          queryParams: { 
            entity: JSON.stringify('user') 
          } 
        };
        this.router.navigate(['/'], navigationExtras);
      }
    }
```